How to get the test with the highest score if enrollment date and test date are the same?
I have a dataset and I am trying to test the efficiency of a pre-enrollment course. I have enrollment date, test date, subject and the results. The students are grouped into

group 1 - 30 days before enrollment
group 2 - 30 days after enrollment
group 3 - 45 days before enrollment up to 35 days after enrollment.

Each registration ID should fall into one group 1 being first priority, group 2 being second priority and group 3 being last. However, a student may have multiple tests on the same day but we should capture the registration id with the highest test score. If student falls out of the -45 days to 30 days after enrollment they are should be written as not classified​
Below is the data:
data <- data.frame(
      student_id = c("a53e83bzz", "a53e83bzz", "a53e83bzz", "2034cccc", "2034cccc", "2034cccc", "2034cccc", "202353bbbb", "202353bbbb", "1980polkfbb", "1980polkfbb"),
 registration_id = c("a53-ffe9", "a53-ffe9", "a53-ffe9", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", "202-ffcc", "202-ffcc", "198-ffb", "198-ffb"),
 subject = c("maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "english", "english", "english", "english"),
enrollment_date = as.Date(c("2021-02-28", "2021-02-28", "2021-02-28", "2019-03-25", "2019-03-25", "2019-03-25", "2019-03-25", "2021-05-22", "2021-05-22", "2019-07-04", "2019-07-04"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
test_score_category = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2),
test_date = as.Date(c("2021-02-27", "2021-02-27", "2022-07-08", "2019-02-18", "2019-03-11", "2020-04-07", "2020-04-07", "2021-06-17", "2021-06-07", "2019-03-14", "2019-03-28"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
difference = c(-1, -1, 495, -35, -14, 379, 379, 26, 16, -112, -98)
 )

This is what I have tried in R, but I am not getting the exact results I want.
result <- data %>%
group_by(student_id, registration_id) %>%
arrange(student_id, group) %>%  # Prioritize by group (1 > 2 > 3)
slice_max(order_by = test_score_category) %>%  
ungroup()

Below is the result I am expecting
df <- data.frame(
  student_id = c("a53e83bzz", "2034cccc", "202353bbbb", "1980polkfbb"),
  registration_id = c("a53-ffe9", "203-ffde", "202-ffcc", "198-ffb"),
  subject = c("maths", "maths", "english", "english"),
  enrollment_date = as.Date(c("2021-02-28", "2019-03-25", "2021-05-22", "2019-07-04"), format="%Y-%m-%d"),
  test_score_category = c(1, 0, 0, NA),  # Use NA for not_classified
  test_date = as.Date(c("2021-02-27", "2019-03-11", "2021-06-07", NA), format="%Y-%m-%d"),  # Use NA for not_classified
  difference = c(-1, -14, 16, NA)  # Use NA for not_classified
  )


library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(group = case_when(between(difference, -30, 0) ~ 1,
                           between(difference, 0, 45) ~ 2,
                           between(difference, -45, 30) ~ 3)) |>
  slice_min(data.frame(group, difference, -test_score_category), by = student_id) |> 
  mutate(across(c(starts_with("test"), "difference"), ~ replace(.x, is.na(group), NA))) |>
  select(-group)

#   student_id registration_id subject enrollment_date test_score_category
#1   a53e83bzz        a53-ffe9   maths      2021-02-28                   1
#2    2034cccc        203-ffde   maths      2019-03-25                   0
#3  202353bbbb        202-ffcc english      2021-05-22                   0
#4 1980polkfbb         198-ffb english      2019-07-04                  NA
#   test_date difference
#1 2021-02-27         -1
#2 2019-03-11        -14
#3 2021-06-07         16
#4       <NA>         NA

Data:
> dput(data)
structure(list(student_id = c("a53e83bzz", "a53e83bzz", "a53e83bzz", 
"2034cccc", "2034cccc", "2034cccc", "2034cccc", "202353bbbb", 
"202353bbbb", "1980polkfbb", "1980polkfbb"), registration_id = c("a53-ffe9", 
"a53-ffe9", "a53-ffe9", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", "203-ffde", 
"202-ffcc", "202-ffcc", "198-ffb", "198-ffb"), subject = c("maths", 
"maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "maths", "english", 
"english", "english", "english"), enrollment_date = structure(c(18686, 
18686, 18686, 17980, 17980, 17980, 17980, 18769, 18769, 18081, 
18081), class = "Date"), test_score_category = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2), test_date = structure(c(18685, 18685, 19181, 
17945, 17966, 18359, 18359, 18795, 18785, 17969, 17983), class = "Date"), 
    difference = c(-1, -1, 495, -35, -14, 379, 379, 26, 16, -112, 
    -98)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))


thank you. how do I modify the code to select the test date closest to the enrollment date even when they are in the same group? for example a student has difference of -28 and -14 (hence in group 1), currently it is taking -28 but I want it to take -14 (because it is closer)

slice_min above looks at three variables: data.frame(group, difference, -test_score_category). Can you try replacing difference with abs(difference)? Logic: Currently the -28 is taken (the minimum), but using abs() it would yield the values 28 and 14 and amongst them, 14 is the minimum.

Base request
For the basic task of conditional grouping by the date difference, and keeping a single group assignation per student_id, the following should work:
library(dplyr)

data |> 
  mutate(
    group = case_when(
      -30 <= difference & difference <= 0  ~ "1",
      0    < difference & difference <= 30 ~ "2",
      -45 <= difference & difference <= 35 ~ "3",
      .default = NA
    ) |> 
      factor(level = c("1", "2", "3"))
  ) |> 
  arrange(student_id,group) |> 
  slice_head(n = 1,by = student_id)

The trick used here is to rely on factors being ordered by their level to ensure they are sorted as required by arrange(), and keep one line per student_id.
Detailed matching
To replicate fully what you shared as df:
data |> 
  mutate(
    group = case_when(
      -30 <= difference & difference <= 0  ~ "1",
      0    < difference & difference <= 30 ~ "2",
      -45 <= difference & difference <= 35 ~ "3",
      .default = NA
    ) |> factor(level = c("1", "2", "3"))
  ) |> 
  arrange(desc(student_id),group,difference,desc(test_score_category)) |> 
  slice_head(n = 1,by = student_id) |> 
  mutate(
    test_score_category = if_else(is.na(group), NA, test_score_category),
    test_date = if_else(is.na(group), NA, test_date),
    difference = if_else(is.na(group), NA, difference)
  ) |> 
  select(-group)

